# OpenGL component for VCL (C++Builder)

Tags: c++, opengl, vcl

Anyone know of a VCL component for displaying OpenGL 3D graphics? We've been using a component from about 20 years ago. While it works fine by itself, if we try to instance more than one we get spurious OpenGL errors ( display lists fail, etc.). We only use OpenGL 1.1 at this time.

Comment: Sorry that I can't help. Did you try [Torry's](https://torry.net/) and the usual suspects?

Answer (score 1):

Theres GLScene it seems active still http://glscene.sourceforge.net/wikka/

Comment: Major upvote ! The [gallery](http://glscene.sourceforge.net/wikka/gallery_demos.htm) is impressive